# How can I show $2|x|-3\geq{|x-1|}$ using this theorem?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

The Theorem is as follows:

For any numbers x and y, the following statements are true:

1. $|x|<y$ if and only if $-y<x<y$
2. $|x|\leq{y}$ if and only if $-y\leq{x}\leq{y}$
3. $|x|\geq{y}$ if and only if either $x\leq{-y}$ or $x\geq{y}$
4. $|x|>y$ if and only if either $x<{-y}$ or $x>{y}$

Here's my progress so far,
$2|x|-3\geq{|x-1|}\\ 
\implies 2\left(|x|-\frac{3}{2}\right)\geq{|x-1|}\\ 
         \implies |x|\geq{\frac{|x-1|}{2}+\frac{3}{2}}\\
         \implies |x|\geq{\frac{|x-1|+3}{2}} \text{ can now use part 3.}\\
         \implies x\leq{\frac{-|x-1|-3}{2}} \lor x\geq{\frac{|x-1|+3}{2}}\\$

I had this idea of replacing $|x-1|$ with 1 since it is the distance from 1 to x on the number line, but that is flawed since we could've done this initially and gotten the answer. I'm not sure where to go from here. Maybe I could've applied part 2 of the proof to the beginning of $|x-1|$ but then I'd arrive at $-(2|x|-3)\leq{|x-1|}\leq{2|x|-3}$ which doesn't help me at all. Any tips or hints?

Comment: For $x=0$ you have $-3\ge 1$.  Try something else.

Comment: This isn't always true.  $x =0$......

Comment: @herbsteinberg Of course it's not true for $x=0$, the inequality is only true at certain intervals.

Comment: "the inequality is only true at certain intervals. " then you should have *STATED* that.  You title is "2|x|−3≥|x−1|?"  Well, you *CAN'T* show that because is is *NOT* true.  And if you *KNEW* it wasn't true you should not have *ASKED*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm... well, to take a mallet and force things to fit.

$2|x|-3 \ge |x-1| \iff$

$-2(|x| - 3) \le x-1 \le 2|x| - 3\iff$

$-2|x|+3 \le x-1 \le 2|x| - 3 \iff$

($-2|x|+3 \le x-1$) and ($x -1 \le 2|x|-3$)$\iff$

($-2|x|\le x-4$) and ($x + 2 \le 2|x|$)$\iff$

($2|x|\ge 4-x$) and $(|x| \ge \frac{x+2}2$)$\iff$

($2x \le x-4$ or $2x\ge 4-x$) and ($x\le -\frac x2 - 1$ or $x \ge \frac x2 + 1$)$\iff$

($x \le -4$ or $3x \ge 4$) and ($\frac 32 x \le -1$ or $\frac 12x \ge 1$)$\iff$

($x\le -4$ or $x\ge \frac 43$) and ($x \le -\frac 23$ or $x \ge 2$)$\iff$

And combining these this can only be true if:

If $x \le -4$ then the LHS and RHS are both true.

If $-4 < x < \frac 43$ then LHS is false so it isnt true.

If $\frac 43 \le x <  2$ then RHS is false so it isn't true.

And if $x \ge 2$ the the LHS and RHS are both true.

So this is true if and only if $x\le -4$ or $x \ge 2$.

......

I really don't recommend forcing yourself to use a theorem when there is a more common sense way of just taking cases where $x <0; 0\le x < 1; x > 1$ and doing it directly.

(that is $x< 0$ then $-2x-3 \ge 1-x\implies x \le -4$.)

($0\le x < 1$ then $2x-3 \ge 1-x$ \implies $x\ge \frac 43$ which it isn't on teh interval $0\le x < 1$.)

($x \ge 1$ then $2x -3 \ge x-1\implies x\ge 2$)

(So $x\le -4$ or $x \ge 2$.)

Comment: This argument makes sense provided $2|x|−3≥−(2|x|−3)$, equivalently, when $|x|≥3/2$.

Answer (score 2):

First, let us consider that $x\geq 1$. Then it results that
\begin{align*}
2|x| - 3 \geq |x-1| & \Longleftrightarrow 2x - 3 \geq x - 1\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow x \geq 2
\end{align*}

Thus the first solution set is given by $S_{1} = [2,\infty)$.

Second, let us consider that $0\leq x\leq 1$. Then it results that
\begin{align*}
2|x| - 3 \geq |x-1| & \Longleftrightarrow 2x - 3 \geq 1 - x\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow 3x \geq 4\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow x\geq \frac{4}{3}
\end{align*}

Thus the second solution set is given by $S_{2} = \varnothing$.

Finally, we can consider the case where $x\leq 0$. Then it results that

\begin{align*}
2|x| - 3 \geq |x-1| & \Longleftrightarrow -2x - 3 \geq 1 - x\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow x\leq -4
\end{align*}

Hence the third solution set is given by $S_{3} = (-\infty,-4]$.

Gathering all results, we arrive at the solution set $S = S_{1}\cup S_{2}\cup S_{3} = (-\infty,-4]\cup[2,+\infty)$.

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You already have one absolute value isolated on one side of the inequality.

$$  |x-1| \leq 2|x| - 3  \text{.}  $$
So apply part 2 to obtain
$$  -(2|x| - 3) \leq x-1 \leq 2|x| - 3  \text{.}  $$

Work on $-(2|x| - 3) \leq x-1$ and $x-1 \leq 2|x| - 3$ separately, isolating the remaining absolute value in each.  Now recall that *both* of these must be true at the same time and take the intersection of the results from each inequality.

Comment: This argument makes sense only if $2|x|-3 \geq -(2|x|-3)$,  equivalently, when $|x|\geq 3/2$.

Comment: @Medo: Take it up with the theorem -- it has been applied exactly as the OP has recited it.

Comment: Indeed, the theorem should read for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $y\geq 0$..., but again this should be understood implicitly.

Comment: @Medo :   "How can I show ... using this theorem?"  "The theorem is ...".  Any Answer that does not apply the theorem as recited is non-responsive to the Question.  If you have an issue with the recitation of the theorem, that belongs in comments to the Question.  No amount of commenting on this Answer will correct deficiencies in the Question.